# How do I plot a map in Tableau for zip codes with 0 digit in the beginning?

Tags: excel, dictionary, tableau-api, zipcode

I am new to tableau and trying to create a map as visualiztion

I have zip code information from survey data that is in the form as below:
Row

```
 A1   ZCTA5 00601
 A2   ZCTA5 99929
```

I removed the text `'ZCTA5'` but then zips which start with 00 only take the form 601
I also tried to use `=TEXT(A1,"00")` but that will only change it for numbers which have 3 digit zip codes.

if I use the zip as they are, the map is incorrect and shows me latitude and longitudes of countries that are not in America.

How do I restructure the data for me to be able to use it as a maps in tableau?
Unfortunately it adds 00 to even zip codes with 99929

Comment: Don't treat a zip code as a number: treat it as a string. The problems you are having are caused by interpreting the zip code portion of the string as a number.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding this correctly you want to make sure that all of your zip codes are padded correctly. If that is the case you can use the following formula:

```
=TEXT(Cell,"00000")
```

For example:

```
    A 
1 00654
2 95842
3 00243
4 00001
```

Will be represented as

```
 A 
1 654
2 95842
3 243
4 1
```

In excel but applying the formula `=TEXT(Cell,"00000")` to each cell you get the correct format

```
  A        B
1 654   00654
2 95843 95843
3 2343  02343
4 1     00001
```

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate the need for consistently editing these fields in Excel by bringing the data into Tableau as-is. You can shape the text in many ways using Tableau's native features or a calculated field.

**If the data represented in Excel is as such:**

```
ID     Zip
1      123
2      12345
3      12
4      1
```

Then you can bring it in exactly as it is. From there you will need to tell Tableau that it is a Zip Code: (Tableau, in this example, will see that the field is named "Zip" and will automatically associate to Zip Code data type. If the field were named something like "Blah", though you would have to do the following.)

```
First, ensure that the field is brought to the Dimensions pane (Blue)
-Then-
Right Click on the Field > Geographic Role > ZIP Code
```

The result will be that leading zeros are added to each to make 5 digit zip codes.

**IF the string being brought into Tableau is "A1   ZCTA5 00601":**

You can simply take the farthest right 5 digits from the string as such:

```
RIGHT([Zip Code String], 5)
```

From there you can force Tableau to recognize the field as a Zip Code:

```
Right Click on Calculated Field > Geographic Role > ZIP Code
```

Comment: Did this work for you? If so, please apply the green check/tick. If not, please let me know or post an answer that did end up working for you. Thank you!